# Semantic UI DropDown with Floating not working

Tags: semantic-ui

Normal dropdown elements are work fine but floating dropdown elements not work.

I have `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();` in my script file. I would like to make dropdown as [Semantic UI (DropDown)](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html).Please see the **Floating** section , you will see as below screen-shoot

[image]

Adding `simple` class is not work well because it is auto open and hide.
What am I missing to work fine this element ? Am I need some scripts to add ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong jQuery version. I need to use jQuery version 2 for Semantic UI.